# how to clone a super DB configuration from one host to another host in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have a super DB in one host. I have the same sub-databases in other host and now I want to create the super DB with same configuration. How to do this?

Please help. It will save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the Configuration Manager. Point your browser to http://your-server:8000/appservices, then click on Configuration Manager. Click the Export tab. Check the boxes next to your super database and click the Export button. That will download a zip file.

Now go to the other server, do the same thing except use the Import tab instead of Export. Click the `Browse...` button, select the .zip file you downloaded in the first step, click the Compare button, and if all looks good, click Apply.

More information on [Configuration Manager](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/config_manager) in the Administrator's Guide.

Answer (score 1):

All the database configuration details will be available in this file /var/opt/MarkLogic/databases.xml in marklogic server. SO that you can copy your database configuration from one host to another host database xml. You can try like this